# What does AT_MOST refers to?

Tags: android, view

As we all know, there are three mode in `MeasureSpec`. They are `AT_MOST`,`EXACTLY`,`UNSPECIFIED`. I know what are the other two mode refer two, but still can't get the meaning of `AT_MOST` from the reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AT_MOST` means that the child can be any size up to and including the size of the `MeasureSpec`.

For example, having a `MeasureSpec` of size `100, 100` and a mode of `AT_MOST` would allow the child to have `width <= 100` and `height <= 100`

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#AT_MOST

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when the mode is AT_MOST and width and height is specific the same as parent view, is AT_MOST the same as UNSPECIFIC now.For example width and height of parent view are both 100, we set width and height all 100 and using AT_MOST mode.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `UNSPECIFIED` allows the size to be **anything**, even larger than the parent. Treat the statements in the documentation literally and you should be fine.

Comment: I know it now. But i have another question, is it impossible that the width and height are larger then its parent. Something like child view override parent view.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure for every case. Open up a new question to get more eyes on it.